# Matrix with a zero eigenvalue and an inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my research, I came across the infinite dimensional Hermitian matrix

$$M_{nm}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}\Big(2n\delta_{n,m+1}+(4n+3)\delta_{n,m}+(2n+3)\delta_{n,m-1}\Big)$$

It has a zero eigenvalue with eigenvector $v_n=(-1)^n$. Typically this should mean there is no inverse, however the matrix

$$(M^{-1})_{nm}=(-1)^{n+m}\frac{(2\cdot\text{max}(n,m))!!}{(2\cdot\text{max}(n,m)+1)!!}$$

where $\text{max}(n,m)$ equals $n$ when $n\geq m$ and $m$ when $m\geq n$, is an inverse in the sense that $MM^{-1}=M^{-1}M=1$.

How is this possible?

Comment: It’s definitely not possible for a matrix with an eigenvalue of 0 to have an inverse because $M^{-1}Mx = M^{-1}0x = 0 \ne x$

Comment: Your candidate for $M^{-1}$ has infinitely many non-zero entries in its rows and columns. How do you multiply such matrices?

Comment: @LucashWindowWasher It would be very helpful if you provided a link to where you found out about this matrix and its inverse.

Comment: @Christoph the matrix $M$ is tridiagonal, so the matrix multiplication between the two picks out only three terms in the sum, so it should be well defined.

Comment: @LucashWindowWasher But $M^{-1} v$ is not defined for all $v$, regardless of $M$ only picking up finitely many things.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer I don't have a link or reference, the first matrix came out of constructing a vector operator of $SL(3,R)$, and I found the inverse.

Comment: @Christoph so are you saying that since $M^{-1}$ is not well defined on the vector space, it cannot be considered an inverse?

Comment: @LucashWindowWasher Yes indeed!

Comment: @Christoph I think if I put this on a Hilbert space, with the simple inner product $(u,v)=\sum_n u*_n v_n$, then $(-1)^n$ will no longer be in the vector space. And since a vector in this space will have to fall off like $n^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha > 1/2$, $M^{-1}v$ should be well defined.

Comment: @LucashWindowWasher Sure, if you get rid of the eigenvalue $0$ by restricting to an $M$-invariant complement of the kernel, you might get something invertible.